# How to exclude rows that have matching fields in other rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access 2013 that has a number of different columns. As part of the data that is entered into the main table, there are duplicates in certain columns. However when I 'pot up' the volumes of rows based on their status, I need to be able to exclude those with the same values in other columns.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
HeaderID | Date      | Number | EffectiveDate | Reg | Status
------------------------------------------------------------
    2    | 01/01/2016| 100001 |   01/12/2015  |  01 | Ready
    3    | 01/01/2016| 100001 |   01/12/2015  |  02 | Ready
    4    | 02/02/2016| 100002 |   12/11/2015  |  R  | Pending
    5    | 02/02/2016| 100002 |   12/11/2015  |  T  | Pending
    6    | 02/02/2016| 100002 |   12/11/2015  |  N  | Pending
    7    | 15/09/2015| 100003 |   30/11/2015  |  01 | Ready
    8    | 14/09/2015| 100004 |   20/02/2016  |  01 | New
```

I have the basic below code already:

```
Select 
    tbl_Progression.Status, 
    Count(tbl_Progression.HeaderID) AS CountofHeaderID
From tbl_Progression
Group By tbl_Progression.Status
```

I'm looking to be able to get the results to look like the below using the example data above, whereby the `Status` is counted by `HeaderID` but only counts once those records that have the same `Date`, `Number` and `EffectiveDate` (but different `Reg`) to look like this:

```
------------------------
Status  | CountofHeaderID
------------------------
Pending |      1
Ready   |      2
New     |      1
```

Instead of what the current code is doing:

```
------------------------
Status  | CountofHeaderID
------------------------
Pending |      3
Ready   |      3
New     |      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  You can, however, use a subquery with `DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`):

```
Select p.Status, Count(*) as new_CountofHeaderID
From (select distinct p.status, p.Date, p.Number, pEffectiveDate
      from tbl_Progression as p
     ) as p
Group By p.Status;
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much. worked first time. Brownie points for you @Gordon Linoff